# Pinpointing how Scrapy is getting redirected, and how to get around it

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, bots

When I pull up a schedule for a mindbodyonline client in a browser, I have no trouble getting the Xpath to the items I want to scrape from the page. However, when I attempt to crawl the site with the scrapy shell, my XPaths never return any objects.

For example, I try and crawl the following URL from the scrapy shell:

```
$ scrapy shell https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/adm/home.asp?studioid=2260

2013-07-15 15:50:45-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
2013-07-15 15:50:46-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
2013-07-15 15:50:46-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-07-15 15:50:46-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-07-15 15:50:46-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-07-15 15:50:46-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-07-15 15:50:46-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-07-15 15:50:46-0700 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2013-07-15 15:50:53-0700 [default] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/ws.asp?studioid=2260> from <GET https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/adm/home.asp?studioid=2260>
2013-07-15 15:50:55-0700 [default] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/ws.asp?studioid=2260&sessionChecked=true> from <GET https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/ws.asp?studioid=2260>
2013-07-15 15:51:01-0700 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/ws.asp?studioid=2260&sessionChecked=true> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   hxs        <HtmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<html>\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t<title>Yoga Now Online'>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/adm/home.asp?studioid=2260>
[s]   response   <200 https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/ws.asp?studioid=2260&sessionChecked=true>
[s]   settings   <CrawlerSettings module=None>
[s]   spider     <BaseSpider 'default' at 0x99480ac>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:32:33) 

In [1]: response.body
Out[1]: '\r\n\t<html>\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t<title>Yoga Now Online</title>\r\n\t<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">\r\n\t<LINK REL="ICON" HREF="/favicon.ico">\r\n\t<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/favicon.ico">\r\n\t<script type="text/javascript">\r\n\r\nvar _gaq = _gaq || [];\r\n_gaq.push([\'_setAccount\', \'UA-19985881-2\']);\r\n_gaq.push([\'_setDomainName\', \'none\']);\r\n_gaq.push([\'_setAllowLinker\', true]);\r\n_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\']);\r\n\r\n(function() {var ga = document.createElement(\'script\'); ga.type = \'text/javascript\'; ga.async = true;\r\nga.src = (\'https:\' == document.location.protocol ? \'https://ssl\' : \'http://www\') + \'.google-analytics.com/ga.js\';\r\nvar s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);\r\n})();\r\n\r\n</script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/styles/jquery.tooltip.css"  /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/styles/base/jquery.ui.all.css"  /><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/plugins/jquery.cookie-1.0.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/plugins/jquery.mb.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/plugins/jquery.libasync.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.core.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.droppable.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.position.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.effects.core.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.effects.highlight.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/plugins/jquery.tooltip.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/plugins/jquery.ba-resize.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/plugins/jquery.lightboxLib.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/plugins/jquery.hoverIntent.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438/scripts/plugins/jquery.smartFocus-0.1.js"></script>\r\n\r\n\r\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\n// filePath must be absolute with leading slash\r\nfunction contentUrl(filePath) {\r\n\t\r\n\treturn "https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438" + filePath;\r\n\t\r\n}\r\n\r\n(function ($) {\r\n\t//$.fn.extend({\r\n\t$.contentUrl = function (filePath) {\r\n\t\t//contentUrl: function (filePath) {\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\treturn "https://static.mindbodyonline.com/v33438" + filePath;\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t};\r\n})(jQuery);\r\n\r\n$(function() {\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\t// init tooltips\r\n\t\t$("img[title],span[title],select[title],input[title],legend[title]").tooltip({\r\n\t\t\ttrack: true,\r\n\t\t\tshowURL: false,\r\n\t\t\tfade: 250\r\n\t\t});\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\r\n\t$(\'fieldset.collapsible\').setCollapseEvents();\r\n\t\r\n});\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n\r\n<script type="text/javascript">\r\n\r\nfunction launchHome() {\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\tdocument.wsLaunch.action = "home.asp?studioid=2260";\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\tdocument.wsLaunch.submit();\r\n\t}\r\n\t</script>\r\n\t</head>\r\n\t<body onLoad="launchHome();">\r\n\t<form name="wsLaunch" action="home.asp?studioid=2260" method="post">\r\n\t<input type="hidden" name="tg" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="vt" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="lvl" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="stype" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="qParam" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="view" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="trn" value="0" /> <input type="hidden" name="page" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="catid" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="prodid" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="date" value="7/16/2013" /> <input type="hidden" name="classid" value="0" /> <input type="hidden" name="sSU" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="optForwardingLink" value="" /> \r\n\t<input type="hidden" name="launchGUID" value="" />\r\n\t<input type="hidden" name="launchUID" value="" />\r\n\t<input type="hidden" name="launchPWDChange" value="" />\r\n\t<input type="hidden" name="launchPWDChangeKey" value="" />\r\n\t<input type="hidden" name="launchLostPWD" value="" />\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n\t<input type="hidden" name="extLink" value="" />\r\n\t</form>\r\n\t<noscript>\r\n\tYou must have javascript enabled to use Yoga Now Online.\r\n\t</noscript>\r\n\t</body>\r\n\t</html>\r\n'
```

Sorry, you need to tidy that HTML, I'll try to attach a pretty version later. But the point is, the data I need is not in the response via `scrapy crawl`. But, When I go to the URL manually, or even with `view(response)`

The following HTML is present (This is the data I want to crawl):

```
<tr class="oddRow" style="width: 929px;">
<td style="width: 90px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4:00&nbsp;pm </td><td style="width: 167px;"></td>
<td style="width: 172px;"><a class="modalClassDesc" name="cid617" href="javascript:;">Vinyasa (Level 1-2)</a></td>
<td style="width: 172px;"><a class="modalBio" name="bio100000375" href="javascript:;">Dietrich McGaffey</a></td>
<td style="width: 106px;">Main Yoga Room</td><td style="width: 162px;">&nbsp;1&nbsp;hour&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;30&nbsp;minutes</td></tr>
```

So the preceding was the big picture, and I hope you have a good idea on what I am trying to accomplish. The HTML I want to scrape is available in the browser but not via the scrapy shell. I understand that Scrapy is getting redirected off the bat. Based on the time I've spent investigating, I believe the problem is the website has javascript detection to deter bots, or it may be that scrapy is not processing the cookie correctly.

And to confuse myself further, this is the output from cURL:

```
curl https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/adm/home.asp?studioid=2260
<head><title>Object moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This object may be found <a HREF="/ASP/ws.asp?studioid=2260">here</a>.</body>
```

When I follow the link from cURL, it seems it sends me on an infinite loop of object moved links.

Sorry, for being verbose, but I wanted to describe my problem thoroughly. If anyone has either a solution, or pointer how to further investigate, I would value your input. Thank you for taking the time to tray and help me.

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome, I get redirected from https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/adm/home.asp?studioid=2260
to https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/home.asp?studioid=2260
(see edit below for an explanation)

Sitll using Chrome, view-source:https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/home.asp?studioid=2260 shows that the page contains a frameset

```
<frameset id="mainFrameset" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" NORESIZE>   
  <frame name="mainFrame" src="main_class.asp?tg=&amp;vt=&amp;lvl=&amp;stype=&amp;view=&amp;trn=0&amp;page=&amp;catid=&amp;prodid=&amp;date=7%2F16%2F2013&amp;classid=0&amp;sSU=&amp;optForwardingLink=&amp;qParam=&amp;justloggedin=&amp;nLgIn=&amp;pMode=" frameborder="10"  scrolling="YES" width="320">
</frameset>
<noframes> 
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" text="#000000">
</body>
</noframes> 
</html>
```

So I think you need to fetch the page corresponding to the @src attribute of frame[@name="mainFrame"]

Still under Chrome, view-source:https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/main_class.asp?tg=&vt=&lvl=&stype=&view=&trn=0&page=&catid=&prodid=&date=7%2F16%2F2013&classid=0&sSU=&optForwardingLink=&qParam=&justloggedin=&nLgIn=&pMode=
indeed has the `<table id="classSchedule-mainTable" class="" cellspacing="0">` you are looking for

---

Edit: I tested this using scrapy shell like this (I like to use lxml.etree directly)

```
  import lxml.etree
  import lxml.html
  doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(response.body, parser=lxml.html.HTMLParser())
  print lxml.etree.tostring(doc.xpath('head')[0], pretty_print=True)
```

and it happens the redirect in the browser comes from a little bit of Javascript (I'm not sure what this does, but it seems to match the behaviour)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">&#13;
&#13;
function launchHome() {&#13;
    &#13;
            document.wsLaunch.action = "home.asp?studioid=2260";&#13;
        &#13;
        document.wsLaunch.submit();&#13;
    }&#13;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="launchHome();">&#13;
```

`response.url` being:

```
  response.url
  'https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/ws.asp?studioid=2260&sessionChecked=true'
```

You get that redirection to https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/ASP/home.asp?studioid=2260.

Comment: I'm now looking into the user_agent setting in the downloader middleware, but I still am compelled to believe javascript detection is the culprit, and I will need to find a way to solve this. Thank you for your input.